# PHPMailer : Cant send attachement

Tags: file, phpmailer, rar

I have a probleme with PHPMailer .

First i used it without FTP , but all email was  SPAM .

So i tried to use my FTP login  and now all email are not  junk .

But problem ...   my attachement   ( .rar   and . zip )    doest work .

i tried with   txt files and its ok ...   i'm becoming crazy

```
require('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "r******";
$mail->Port = "465";
//usually the port for TLS is 587, for SSL is 465 and non-secure is 25
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
//TLS, SSL or  delete the line
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 's*****';
$mail->Password = '##';
$mail->From = 'sales@*****';
$mail->FromName = '****';
$mail->AddAddress("$payer_email", "$payer_business_name");
$mail->Subject = "SUBJET";
$mail->Body = " MY MESSAGE";

if( $custom == 1 )
{

$mail->AddAttachment('test.txt');
}
if( $custom == 2 )
{

$mail->AddAttachment('test2.txt');
}

$mail->Send() ;
}
}
fclose ($fp);
```

}

i use  if and else because its a paypal button with param .   (  if 1 i send this file by mail )

this is working with txt files .  but  not with  RAR or ZIP files ... No email send

any idea ?

thanks a lot

Comment: i forgot to say , that  no email is send  when i put rar files .    email doesnt work and crash sending when its rar files ..  or the server block

Comment: Overzealous filtering on the receiving end would be my guess. I often encounter mailservers which just flat out refuse .zip or .rar files as attachments.

Comment: using PHPmailer whithout SMTP   works with rar files .   but its goes directly in SPAM  .         the mailserver accepted it .  thats why i'm becoming crazy

Comment: i tried with windows live mail and same smtp setting to send RAR files to the same email . and its work.   i think that its not a probleme with mailserver that refuse rar

Comment: i have just tried with pdf file : not working .. no email sent